# WAR name based on Environment in BuildConfig.groovy

Tags: grails, deployment, ggts, grails-2.4

I want to name my WAR files automatically depending on `appName`, `appVersion` and the short name of `Environment.current`. I have the following option setup in `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
String currentEnvShortName = Environment.envNameMappings.find{it.value == Environment.current.name}.key

def f = new File("grails-app/conf/config.properties")
f.text = ""
f << "Current Env: ${currentEnvShortName}"

grails.project.war.file = "target/war/${appName}-${appVersion.toString().replaceAll(/\./,' ').split().join("-")}${currentEnvShortName}.war"
```

I write the environment to a file so that I don't have to wait for the `war` command to execute. **EDIT: USING GGTS COMMAND LINE**. First, I thought everything works as expected. My usual deployment process is as follows:

1. run `grails clean`
2. run `war` command for the desired environment
3. deploy WAR on application server

After clean, however, and possibly also after other grails commands, the value of `Environment.current` changes in a way I do not understand. It is always `dev` the first time I run the `war` command. After this first time, the environment name is retrieved correctly again. So what I do as a workaround is:

1. run `grails clean`
2. run `war` command for the desired environment, but break right after starting it
3. run `war` command for the desired environment
4. deploy WAR on application server

Am I doing anything wrong or is this a bug?

Environment to reproduce:

GGTS 3.6.4 RELEASE

Grails 2.4.2

Groovy 2.3.10

JDK 1.6.0_07

**EDIT:** I could not reproduce using Grails from regular command line. This behaviour only occurs with Groovy Grails Tool Suite's built in command line. The Environment seems to be switching randomly.

**EDIT 2:** OS: Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue only occurs with the built in command line of Groovy Grails Tool Suite on Windows. If the `war` command is executed from Windows CMD, then the environment  is used correctly.

However, when executing from Windows CMD, encoding breaks for me. I have addressed this specific issue in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874550/grails-on-windows-encoding-errors-when-building-from-windows-cmd).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I tried your scenario multiple times but couldn't able to reproduce that. But, if it is not working for your for some reason, you can use the another approach as follows:

Modify your code in your `BuildConfig.groovy` like:

```
// Define a custom mapping so that you can easily extend for custom environments (which will not be possible via "Environment.current.envNameMappings"
Map envNameMappings = [test: "test", development: "dev", production: "prod"]

// Read the currrent environment from System property
String currentEnv = System.getProperty("grails.env")

println currentEnv
// And this is the short name of environment you want
println envNameMappings[currentEnv]
```

Comment: I could reproduce it in a newly created project; however, the issue does only occur with GGTS (Eclipse) command line. I updated my answer. I wonder what is executed differently with Eclipse. Seems as if it is not always getting the current Environment correctly.